# How to implement firebase auth and flutter app with multiple role base users

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have created a admin app and I want to manage other one user to do some sort of actions with firebase auth login. They can login with firebase auth but I want to have a list of another users and add delete those users. But when come to delete users I getting an error with delete another user.

These are my functions but when deleteUser(userid) It shows "The method 'deleteUser' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseAuth'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'deleteUser'"

[image]

```
void addCounter({
    required String name,
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    print('on add counter');
    try {
      await auth
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)
          .then((value) => {
                FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection("SuperUsers")
                    .doc(value.user!.uid)
                    .set({
                  'role': "counter",
                  'uid': value.user!.uid,
                  'name': name,
                })
              });
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      // this is solely for the Firebase Auth Exception
      // for example : password did not match
      print(e.message);
      // Get.snackbar("Error", e.message!);
      Get.snackbar(
        "Error",
        e.message!,
        snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
      );
    } catch (e) {
      // this is temporary. you can handle different kinds of activities
      //such as dialogue to indicate what's wrong
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  Future<void> deleteCounter(String userId) async {
    try {
      // Step 1: Remove user from Firebase Authentication
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.deleteUser(userId);
      // Step 2: Remove user data from Firestore
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('SuperUsers')
          .doc(userId)
          .delete();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  Future<void> updateUser(
      {required String userId, required String name}) async {
    try {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('SuperUsers')
          .doc(userId)
          .update({
        'name': name,
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  static Stream<List<CounterModel>> counterStream() {
    return firebaseFirestore
        .collection('SuperUsers')
        .snapshots()
        .map((QuerySnapshot query) {
      List<CounterModel> counters = [];
      for (var counter in query.docs) {
        final counterItem =
            CounterModel.fromDocumentSnapshot(snapshot: counter);

        counters.add(counterItem);
      }
      return counters;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the right way to have a list of users and managing that.
One example (and it's the reason that gives you error), you cannot delete users with `FirebaseAuth.instance.deleteUser(userId)` except if you're currently signed with the user you want to delete.
So, you should have a database to managing users (using for example FirebaseStorage) and giving attributes to them, you can give roles, names, ecc.
When you want to delete some users, you have to check if the role permits the user to do that, and if so you can just delete that document from the database.